# How do I get the nth order # for a customer's purchase with pandas?

Tags: pandas, data-science

Let's say hypothetically I have a dataframe like this:

```
customer_id,purchase_date
A,2019-10-05
A,2019-10-02
A,2019-10-01
A,2019-10-03
B,2019-10-01
B,2019-10-03
C,2019-10-04
```

How do I generate a new column that shows the nth order progression for each customer so that I get a dataframe that looks something like this:

```
customer_id,purchase_date,order_num,
A,4
A,2
A,1
A,3
B,1
B,2
C,1
```

Comment: What if there are two orders on the same day for the same customer?

Answer (score 3):

You can do `groupby().cumcount()`:

```
df['order_num'] = df.sort_values('purchase_date').groupby('customer_id').cumcount() + 1
```

Output:

```
  customer_id purchase_date  order_num
0           A    2019-10-05          4
1           A    2019-10-02          2
2           A    2019-10-01          1
3           A    2019-10-03          3
4           B    2019-10-01          1
5           B    2019-10-03          2
6           C    2019-10-04          1
```